# MongoDB Join 3 Collection

Tags: mongodb, join, lookup

i now create 3 collection. ( users , business , business_info ) 
I want to join everything.

users.user_id -> business.user_id |
business.business_id -> business_info.business_id

I am very happy if you can help in this matter.

thank you.

Comment: Can you provide an example ?  You should have a look [to the lookup operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Answer (score -1):

You can join two collection in Mongo by using lookup

```
db.firstCollection.aggregate({
    $lookup:{
        from:"seconedCollection",
        localField:"commonKey", 
        foreignField:"commonKey",
        as:"firstCollection_seconedCollection"
    } 
})
```

Comment: thank you I can connect two collection with this method. But how do I link the third collection to the second collection?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do so. Is it a good idea to use SQL modelling patterns and misuse aggregation tools to makr MongoDB fit that misguided way? Not so much.